# How can Spider-Man wear tennis shoes?

Tags: spider-man, marvel, the-amazing-spider-man-2

Normally, portrayals of Spider-Man that are realistically drawn, or live-action, have him wearing foot skins inspired by martial art fighters; sometimes it has a clearly separate big toe.

It's difficult enough to suppose that Spider-Man covers his skin at all, if his power is explained by gecko-like hairs with microfiber tips. Perhaps they go through thin spandex or special glove material.

But in *The Amazing Spider-Man 2*, he was very clearly wearing athletic shoes with a thick sole, with a thick layer covering the bottom of his feet.

Why did they design his costume that way? What is the rational for its ability to work for him?

Comment: The purported duplicate does not answer this question.  This is getting fresh upvotes; maybe it can be re-opened?  How might I edit it to be more acceptable to this community?